# BeforeUpdate event of a linked subform control firing multiple times

Tags: ms-access, vba

Good afternoon,

I have to maintain an Access form which contain a linked subform (using Master and Child fields).

Basically, in the main form, the user choose a value in a combobox and the subform is automatically updated.

My issue is that I have a BeforeUpdate event on one field of my subform which is preventing to update the field (Cancel=true) when it does not meet the criteria. The alert msgbox should appear once if there is any error in the field but the BeforeUpdate event is always fired 3 times for unknown reason.

I have created a simple accdb file which reproduce my issue. It is located here: https://www.hightail.com/download/bXBhU2V0Q1JxRTFsQXNUQw.

Open the Form1, choose a value in the combobox and then try to update one of the letters in the subform by X and you will get the msgbox appearing multiple times.

Thanks in advance for your help on this issue as it's driving me crazy.

Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you do not change the value of Text0 back to what it was.

Try this

```
Private Sub Text0_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.Text0 = "X" Then
        MsgBox "Wrong value"
        Cancel = True
        Me.Text0.Undo
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @DivisionX but I would like to understand why it's behaving that way. If i open my subform as a main form directly (Form2 in my example) and I update the field with incorrect content, the BeforeUpdate will be fired only once as it should be. 

What are the sequence of events which lead to this event being fired multiple times in the case of linked subform??

Comment: This is just a theory, but could it be that it first tries to update form 1, then form 2, and then form 1 again because form 2 is a subform of from 1?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and watch the execution flow..Events in access are chained and in a specific order...

Answer (score 0):

OK finally found the solution.

It was related to the text box used for storing the Link master fields used by my subform. This control contains the value of my combobox in order to filter out my subform.

The control source definition of this link master field used to be:

```
=myCombobox.column(0)
```

By replacing the definition by just:

```
=myCombobox
```

The beforeUpdate event in my linked subform is only triggered once and behaves as expected;

```
Private Sub Text0_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.Text0 = "X" Then
        MsgBox "Wrong Value"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I can not explained the magic of why it is behaving that way but this is how I made it worked.

Sylvain